# Different NuGet package based on operating system

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2, nuget

I have a test project in dotnet 2.1 that needs to work across multiple platforms (specifically, windows and linux-based systems) as well as access DB2 databases.

IBM provides separate NuGet packages for different operating systems:

1. IBM.Data.DB2.Core
2. IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx
3. IBM.Data.DB2.Core-osx

**How can I specify in my `.csproj` file that I want to use different packages based on the operating system?**

Passing in the `RuntimeIdentifier` (`dotnet publish ... -r linux-x64`) is possible, but I am unsure how to leverage that information inside the `csproj`. I am also not opposed to using the `Choose/When` construct, but don't know how to infer what system is trying to build the project.

Comment: @martin-ullrich offers some ideas here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9794#issuecomment-415992784

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but I added what I ended up going with as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `IsOsPlatform(platform)` MSBuild property function:

```
<PackageReference Include="NetVips.Native.linux-x64" Version="8.9.1" Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform('Linux'))" />
<PackageReference Include="NetVips.Native.osx-x64" Version="8.9.1" Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform('OSX'))" />
<PackageReference Include="NetVips.Native.win-x64" Version="8.9.1" Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOsPlatform('Windows'))" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022#msbuild-property-functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using `Configuration` and the `Choose/When` paradigm.

A simple example `.csproj` would be

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Docker</Configurations>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ... the rest of your .csproj and dependencies ...

  <Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Docker' ">
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx" Version="1.2.2.100" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="1.2.2.100" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>

</Project>
```

On the command line I would run: `dotnet build /your/project.csproj -c <yourConfigurationName>`.

I found [this site](https://blog.submain.com/net-build-configuration-system/) useful for helping set this up in visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to do the same thing with `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore` libraries (which use `IBM.Data.DB2.Core`), here's how I got it to work.

Add RuntimeIdentifiers, otherwise the `RuntimeIdentifier` variable will be empty for dependent projects:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;osx-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

If `RuntimeIdentifier` is set, use that to determine which package to install, otherwise just go based on the operating system. This way we can use `dotnet build --runtime linux-x64` or Visual Studio to build.

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier) != ''">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('win'))" Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0.300" />
      <PackageReference Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('osx'))" Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-osx" Version="3.1.0.300" />
      <PackageReference Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('linux'))" Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx" Version="3.1.0.300" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('Windows'))" Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0.300" />
      <PackageReference Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('OSX'))" Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-osx" Version="3.1.0.300" />
      <PackageReference Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('Linux'))" Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx" Version="3.1.0.300" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

I also wanted to copy the license file from the project to the nuget directory:

```
<Target Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('Windows'))" Name="PreBuildWin" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier) == ''" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('win'))" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('osx'))" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core-osx\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('linux'))" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core-lnx\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>

<Target Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('OSX')) Or $([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('Linux'))" Name="PreBuildUnix" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier) == '' And $([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('OSX'))" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(HOME)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core-osx\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier) == '' And $([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('Linux'))" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(HOME)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core-lnx\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('win'))" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(HOME)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('osx'))" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(HOME)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core-osx\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
  <Copy Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('linux'))" SourceFiles="db2consv_is.lic" DestinationFolder="$(HOME)\.nuget\packages\ibm.data.db2.core-lnx\3.1.0.300\buildTransitive\clidriver\license" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

dotnet SDK used: `3.1.402`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx" Version="1.3.0.100" Condition="'$(OSTYPE)' == 'linux-gnu'" />
<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core-osx" Version="1.3.0.100" Condition="'$(OSTYPE)' == 'darwin18'"/>
<PackageReference Include="IBM.Data.DB2.Core" Version="1.3.0.100"  Condition="'$(OSTYPE)' != 'linux-gnu' AND '$(OSTYPE)' != 'darwin18'" />
```

It relies on the fact that Darwin and Linux OSes both set an `OSTYPE` variable. Windows doesn't, hence just the default check for "not Darwin and not Linux".

Comment: Does it support like condition? Condition="'$(OSTYPE)' LIKE '%darwin18%'"

Comment: Sadly, no. Check the [MSBuild Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019) article for details on what it supports. It's pretty limited.

Comment: You can use OSPlatform, which does have a definition for Windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.osplatform?view=net-7.0