# RuntimeIdentifier not available in dependent project when building main project

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, csproj, .net-core-3.1

I have a simple prebuild target in a dependent project (called DAL):

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="RuntimeIdentifier value is: $(RuntimeIdentifier)" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

When I build DAL, everything works as expected:

Command: `dotnet build DAL\DAL.csproj --runtime linux-x64`

Output: `RuntimeIdentifier value is: linux-x64`

But when I build the project that references DAL, the value for `RuntimeIdentifier` disappears:

Command: `dotnet build Transformer\Transformer.csproj --runtime linux-x64`

Output: `RuntimeIdentifier value is:`

I added the `--verbosity d` switch to the build command, and I noticed this:

```
Removing Properties for project "..\DAL\DAL.csproj":
  TargetFramework
  RuntimeIdentifier
```

Why is msbuild doing this and how can I pass the RuntimeIdentifier information to the DAL project when building/publishing the main project?

.NET Core SDK version: `3.1.402`, all projets target `.NET Core 3.1`

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I added the following element to my csproj files:

`<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>`

Now the output is:

```
 Determining projects to restore...
 All projects are up-to-date for restore.
 DAL -> C:\Source\...\DAL\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\linux-x64\DAL.dll
 RuntimeIdentifier value is: linux-x64
 DAL -> C:\Source\...\DAL\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\DAL.dll
 RuntimeIdentifier value is:
 Core -> C:\Source\...\Core\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Core.dll
 Transformer -> C:\Source\...\Transformer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\linux-x64\Transformer.dll
```

It seems like the workaround is to set the `RuntimeIdentifiers` element, is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Runtime Identifiers are more a concern of the entry point application project(s) that will be published, not the library projects.

Previously (1.0 / preview timeframe), the RID (Runtime IDentifier) was forwarded and caused a lot of rebuilds and NuGet inconsistencies with the way the 1.0/1.1 runtime NuGet packages were constructed.

Currently the best way to distribute RID-specific assemblies is building a NuGet packge with the assemblies placed in the right [architecture specific folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#architecture-specific-folders?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-123445).

However, it is also possible to design runtime code that checks [`RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.***)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.isosplatform?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-123445) to choose the right APIs to work with or the right assemblies to load.

Comment: Thanks Martin! The reason I needed this was to install a RID-specific nuget package (IBM DB2 EF Core) in a dependent project when building the main project. I achieved it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63854732/1469494

Comment: If only I knew where this RID are defined. I never did it. They are just there. So if I should not define the: Where can I delete them. I can't even search for them because I don't know what they look like. #MavenDidItRight